# cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.IEnumerable<string> to string[]

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

Trying to solve and getting to following error

```
public String[] Any()
{                            
    var lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 6)).Select(date => date.ToString("MM/yyyy"));

    return lastSixMonths;
}
```

Comment: Its the biggest danger of using `var` for declaring variables. Yes, it remains strong typed, but you can miss the type you are working with.

Comment: You can also change the return type to IEnumerable<string> in case the users of this method want lazy evaluation of the values.

Comment: btw, you could make your `IEnumerable<string>` more simple `.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 6).ToString("MM/yyyy"));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `lastSixMonths` is the `IEnumerable<string>` and you are expecting an array, try this:

```
return lastSixMonths.ToArray();
```

---

I have also created [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0gP1i1) to show how you could print the `string[]`.

Comment: getting System.string[] as output

Comment: "getting Systen.string[] as output"... No, you are not. Your `.Select()` call does return an `IEnumerable<string>` that you have to explicit convert into an array.

Comment: just wanted to display lastsixmonths either in array or string

Comment: after trying ToArray() i am getting System.String[]  as output

Comment: Since it seems @DharmaTeja is having trouble with the array, im adding a very similar answer to this one, trying to make more clear the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
public String[] Any()
{   
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 6)).Select(date => date.ToString("MM/yyyy")).ToArray();
}
```

**Why didn't it work?**

Linq's `Select` returns an `IEnumerable` with filtering, sorting etc, instructions.

It's up to you, to decide what to retrieve, if a single element `FirstOrDefault` or more than one element like `ToList` , `ToArray` , `ToDictionary` etc..

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem**: Your `.Select()` call [does return an IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) that you have to explicit convert into an array.

**An improvement**: There was no need to make two `.Select()` calls one after the other, you could have made with just one call.

```
public String[] Any()
{                            
    IEnumerable<string> lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 6).ToString("MM/yyyy"));
    // Now we convert it into an array.
    string[] returned = lastSixMonths.ToArray();
    return returned;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public String[] Any()
{                            
    IEnumerable<String> lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 6)).Select(date => date.ToString("MM/yyyy"));
    return lastSixMonths.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] Any()
{   
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 6)).Select(date => date.ToString("MM/yyyy")).ToArray();
}
```

**What needs to be understood**

Understand the requirement, fetching 6 months of data from the database using LINQ will provide us a collection of data or multiple rows. So if we want we can limit it by giving condition and using **.FirstorDefault** or if we need an array or in the list format we can use **.ToList** or **.ToArray**.