# how to convert from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'char[]' in C#

Tags: c#, linq

//CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'char[]'.

```
   foreach(string newstr in Reversewords)
    {
       var strArr = newstr.ToCharArray();
        char[] chaArr= strArr.Reverse(); // error in this line
        sb.Append(chaArr);
    }
```

Comment: Does `char[] chaArr= strArr.Reverse().ToArray();` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824777/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-ienumerablestring-to?

Comment: what is Reversewords.

Comment: @Qwerty Looks like it is a collection of strings that are being iterated over.

Comment: Or instead of using the LINQ extension method use the static method of the array class `Array.Reverse` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-6.0#system-array-reverse(system-array)

Comment: In NET 5/6/core you might directly use `sb.AppendJoin("", newstr.Reverse());` No need for the intermediate array buffer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendjoin?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I think you shuold do this in other way, you can first, turn it to string.

Also you can find some intresting things about this here :
[IEnumerable<char> to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654190/ienumerablechar-to-string/11654221#11654221)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `JoinAsString("")`